# Show user details only

Tags: users, user-roles

I have a project where people can enter their details and only they can see those data by log in to there account. 
Instead admin can see all data.

How can i achieve this using wordpress? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not appropriate for this website but you could maybe look for a Wordpress plugin that could help you achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what WordPress does out-of-the-box.

Users can be given an account with username/password for access.
Users then get a private profile page
Administrators of the site (e.g. Users that have the 'Administrator' role assigned) can see their own personal profile data and also everyone's profile data (as they are admins).

plugins can help with adding more field for custom meta data stored for each user.

1) so install Wordpress
2) Add Administators
3) Add Users.
4) Add plugins like [smart-custom-fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/smart-custom-fields/) if you want more than the user meta that WordPress comes with.